# No damage to my hero after installing Diablo 3 Reaper of souls

Tags: diablo-iii

After I installed a Diablo 3 Reaper of souls expansion, I created a new character and decided to restart from the beginning. But my character is not getting any damage and can not die. Anybody knows why? It renders game very easy and boring...

Comment: I've never heard of this happening before. Do you have some other information about your character? What difficulty are you playing on? What type of character are you? What do you mean you restarted? Are you level 70 playing in act 1 or did you start a new character?

Comment: I create a character from scratch (level 1), chose witch doctor. Started at Normal difficulty, but raised it to Hard (now it sais I can't raise it anymore)

Comment: It also seems that I have more money than supposed... and access to my other hero's stash. Thought it was a game feature - share the money and things...

Comment: Is it a legal version of the game?

Comment: LOL, yes, I payed $20 for the upgrade fair and square. And the basic version was also legal. Even my Windows is licensed! :)

Comment: Stashes are shared, as well as bank accounts, across characters, just for the record. Ive never heard of this unnecessary invincibilty issue either, but i play on xb1. Until you fix it though, this would be a great time to get a hardcore character leveled up :)

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem here.  :D

Comment: To confirm, are you playing on PC?

Comment: Please start the game, gather a pack of monsters, (maybe even unequip all your armor) and put your mouse over you life bar. Are you not getting **any** damage even when being hit by 10 zombies, or does your life just regenerate very quickly?

Comment: @ZeroStack: yes, it is the PC version

Comment: @OrcJMR: I tried just working through the game and yes, as you suspected, my hero actually takes some damage, but it restores his points too quickly...

Answer (score 4):

Diablo 3, as of the time of release of *Reaper of Souls*, has a new difficulty system. If it's too easy, quit back out to the title screen and bump it up. I wouldn't expect a new character to take much damage at all unless they were playing on Hard or higher (and there are, like, *fifteen* more difficulty levels available eventually, so there's plenty of room to fine-tune it).

**EDIT:** in 2.0 this is a true difficulty setting, in contrast to the old 'New Game Plus' system that d3 used to use. So if you just jumped in on Normal expecting a challenge, this might be your problem.

[This forum post](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/11835813480) explains the benefits and risks of bumping the difficulty well:

> Raising the difficulty will buff the monster's damage and hit points, and increase some of the rewards (like gold and experience) your character receives. However, monsters will be the same level as you no matter what difficulty you choose.

Comment: It will get a lot more difficult once you get on in levels as well.